# Avro Schema field name: how to include an "illegal" character

Tags: java, avro, parquet

I am trying to create a field name which includes a dot character: `foo.webpage.url`

However the above exception appears:

> Caused by: org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: Illegal character in: foo.webpage.url

I found out that the problem is the two dots "."

Is there a way to give that name to the `schema.field.name`?

Comment: Just a guess, [avro apache](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#names) may help you.

Comment: @hamidovic Did you manage?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. As explained [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#names), you can add fully qualified names where everything until the last word will be considered as name space.

I would suggest add your full avro schema to identify the issue

Comment: Could you please give me an example of a schema for this input json data? `{"name.name":"John"}`. This didn't work: https://gist.github.com/kovacshuni/60ec37e5ff044d9ce23f7b775c9ddae2

Comment: @HunorKovács, this is only possible for the name of record type fields not for other fields